# What does "D.Wiz, X.J. (sorc), S. of Mag. Q." stand for in the Harry Potter: Film Wizardry book?

Tags: harry-potter, props

I received *Harry Potter*: *Film Wizardry* (*Updated Edition*) and the Hogwarts letter seems to be different than in the book and the film, according to how Harry reads it out loud in *Sorcerer's Stone*. At the bottom of the letter it says:

> HOGWARTS SCHOOL OF WITCHCRAFT & WIZARDRY
>   Headmaster: Albus Dumbledore, D.Wiz, X.J. (sorc), S. of Mag. Q.

What does "D.Wiz, X.J. (sorc), S. of Mag. Q." stand for? I think I've figured out that "Wiz" stands for Wizard (this seems pretty obvious), (sorc) stands for sorcerer, and Mag likely stands for Magic, but I don't know what the other letters stand for.

Does anyone know what D.Wiz, X.J. (sorc), S. of Mag. Q. stands for? Is it something real, or just gibberish for the *Film Wizardry* book?

Comment: [Same question on another site](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/f/p/3258895044706350882) (with no real answer).

Comment: Here's wiki the wiki that talks about it. https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Forum:Lots_of_info_from_the_HP_Exhibition,_but_no_time_to_write_entries._Does_anyone_want_it%3F

Comment: @Niffler (with no source, just supposition)

Comment: @Randal'Thor but of course

Comment: Doctor of Wizadry, X.J. (sorc), Sorcerer of Magic, Questionable care giver.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Is that a guess or is it sourced?

Comment: @Slytherincess Part guess, part "joke".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Hmm, I'm going to guess that "X.J." stands for "Xtra Jammin'".

Comment: The [Hogwarts letter "official" replica from MinaLima](https://minalima.com/product/harry-potters-hogwarts-acceptance-letter/), the films' graphic designers, also has the same titles on it, so I don't think it's something specific from that book. (The script isn't the same as the letter, but that doesn't mean it's a different prop.) I did email to ask if they have any information on where the inspiration for those titles came from, and got a reply that said they didn't know :(

Comment: There's an interview with the designer [here](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2019/03/22/a-hidden-treasure-bespoke-handwritten-hogwarts-letters-from-minalima/) which has some cool details, but no specifics on the titles.

Comment: Perhaps "Doctorate of Wizardology, X.J. ([specialty in] sorcery), Society of Magicians, Quidditch (or perhaps Society of Queer Magicians) "

Comment: I wonder where he got them from in the first place. There don't seem to be any wizarding universities.

Comment: At the German synchro they seem to use Dumbledores degrees (Order of Merlin first class, Grand Sorcerer, Chief Warlock, Supreme Mugwump International Confederation of Wizards) But this seems to have no connection to the asked quote

Answer (score 1):

The bona fides “Headmaster: Albus Dumbledore, D.Wiz, X.J. (sorc), S. of Mag. Q.” appeared verbatim at least in the Harry Potter Mini Exhibition at Philatelic Museum circa November 17, 2016 in relation to the release of the film *Fantastic Beast and Where to Find Them*.

One of the exhibits is a letter from Dumbledore, with these credentials:
[image: Dumbledore’s Credentials]

This has also appeared in same form in [MinaLina’s replica acceptance letter.](https://minalima.com/product/harry-potters-hogwarts-acceptance-letter/)
[image: MinaLina Letter]

It has been surmised that the credentials might mean the following:

**D. Wiz.**
Doctorate of Wizardry

**X.J. (sorc.)**
Sorcery specialty

**S. of Mag.**
Society of Magicians

**Q**
Quidditch

There is no official confirmation or endorsement, and from the comments from those who reached out, it appears that at least some of the Harry Potter licensing staff have no idea what these abbreviations mean.

Comment: There's also the question of *where* someone would study a Doctorate of Wizardry, especially as it's implied in the stories that completing wizarding school with enough NEWTs is the highest level of education that really seems to matter. Is such a degree purely honorary, or can someone explicitly enroll in it?

Comment: Why did they just randomly throw in the word ‘Quiddich’?  He never showed any particular interest in the sport.

Comment: It's the only Harry Potter related word they could think of that starts with "Q".

Comment: If it was "Quiddich", it's as random as adding "Soccer" to a list of titles and achievements in the real world. "Quiddich" is a sport, not an achievement or degree. "Top Scorer Class of '68, Quiddich" would be an achievement. So I'm guessing it's not Quiddich.